# mod_rewrite to get rid of index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have spent days in vain to get rewrite rules to work for installation of the OJS program (http://pkp.sfu.ca/?q=ojs) on my dedicate server. My server has Apache 2.4.2 and PHP 5 installed. It has two other PHP programs (a job board and a forum) with rewrite rules for removing index.php working fine. However, for the OJS program, I tried all rules I could find on the net and could not get the rewrite to work. The problem is always redirect looping. Here is the rules I tried in .htaccess (the commented-out lines were tested individually or in combination with others):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

# Use this set of 3 lines for each of your journals
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www.mysite.org
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/index.php/.*
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1" [L,NS] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L] 

# Use this set of 3 lines to allow access to the site level
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www.mysite.org
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "/index.php/index/$1" [QSA,L]


#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www.mysite.org
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1" [L,PT]
```

Below is the Apache error log

```
[Sat Sep 21 00:08:53.413993 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22466] mod_rewrite.c(468):  [www.mysite.com/sid#9a22888][rid#9a725b0/initial] [perdir /home/mysite/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/mysite/public_html/journal -> journal
[Sat Sep 21 00:08:53.414013 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22466] mod_rewrite.c(468):  [www.mysite.com/sid#9a22888][rid#9a725b0/initial] [perdir /home/mysite/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'journal'
[Sat Sep 21 00:08:53.414039 2013] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 22466] mod_rewrite.c(468):  [www.mysite.com/sid#9a22888][rid#9a725b0/initial] [perdir /home/mysite/public_html/] rewrite 'journal' -> '/index.php/journal'
[Sat Sep 21 00:08:53.414051 2013] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 22466] mod_rewrite.c(468):  [www.mysite.com/sid#9a22888][rid#9a725b0/initial] [perdir /home/mysite/public_html/] trying to replace prefix /home/mysite/public_html/ with /
[Sat Sep 21 00:08:53.414061 2013] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 22466] mod_rewrite.c(468):  [www.mysite.com/sid#9a22888][rid#9a725b0/initial] [perdir /home/mysite/public_html/] internal redirect with /index.php/journal [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Sat Sep 21 00:08:53.414109 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22466] mod_rewrite.c(468):  [www.mysite.com/sid#9a22888][rid#9a740c8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/mysite/public_html/] add path info postfix: /home/mysite/public_html/index.php -> /home/mysite/public_html/index.php/journal
[Sat Sep 21 00:08:53.414122 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22466] mod_rewrite.c(468):  [www.mysite.com/sid#9a22888][rid#9a740c8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/mysite/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/mysite/public_html/index.php/journal -> index.php/journal
[Sat Sep 21 00:08:53.414132 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22466] mod_rewrite.c(468):  [www.mysite.com/sid#9a22888][rid#9a740c8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/mysite/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/journal'
[Sat Sep 21 00:08:53.414151 2013] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 22466] mod_rewrite.c(468):  [www.mysite.com/sid#9a22888][rid#9a740c8/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/mysite/public_html/] pass through /home/mysite/public_html/index.php
[Sat Sep 21 00:08:53.414206 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22466] mod_rewrite.c(468):  [www.mysite.com/sid#9a22888][rid#9a80650/subreq] [perdir /home/mysite/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/mysite/public_html/journal -> journal
[Sat Sep 21 00:08:53.414230 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22466] mod_rewrite.c(468):  [www.mysite.com/sid#9a22888][rid#9a80650/subreq] [perdir /home/mysite/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'journal'
[Sat Sep 21 00:08:53.414249 2013] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 22466] mod_rewrite.c(468):  [www.mysite.com/sid#9a22888][rid#9a80650/subreq] [perdir /home/mysite/public_html/] rewrite 'journal' -> '/index.php/journal'
[Sat Sep 21 00:08:53.414260 2013] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 22466] mod_rewrite.c(468):  [www.mysite.com/sid#9a22888][rid#9a80650/subreq] [perdir /home/mysite/public_html/] trying to replace prefix /home/mysite/public_html/ with /
[Sat Sep 21 00:08:53.414267 2013] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 22466] mod_rewrite.c(468):  [www.mysite.com/sid#9a22888][rid#9a80650/subreq] [perdir /home/mysite/public_html/] internal redirect with /index.php/journal [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Sat Sep 21 00:08:53.492920 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22466] mod_rewrite.c(468):  [www.mysite.com/sid#9a22888][rid#9a80650/initial] [perdir /home/mysite/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/mysite/public_html/journal -> journal
[Sat Sep 21 00:08:53.492937 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22466] mod_rewrite.c(468):  [www.mysite.com/sid#9a22888][rid#9a80650/initial] [perdir /home/mysite/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'journal'
```

Could anyone tell me how to get it to work and whether the problem is with mod_rewrite or with the OJS program?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Edit: Now i have tried the following which still has the same problem.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# internally add index.php to all URIs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule !^index\.php index\.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you can use to remove `/index.php` from anywhere in your URLs:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*?/+)index\.php(?:/(.*))?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [L,R]

# internally add index.php to all URIs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule !^index\.php index\.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to answer my question. I added the 3 lines to .htaccess. The rules seem not be working because accessing pages give 404 errors which means "index.php" was not inserted.

Comment: Can anyone else help?

Comment: FIrst of all you need to replace all of your existing code with this. Secondly if URL is `http://site.com/foo/index.php/bar` what do you want this URL to be after redirect?

Comment: Thank you Anubhava. The php program already removes index.php from links in pages, for example, the link to login page looks like: site.com/login. mod_rewrite needs to add the index.php back internally to make the link as site.com/index.php/login otherwise, a 404 will appear.

Comment: I added the 3 lines but with the above two lines commented out. This time I got the old redirect loop issue: `The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.` Cookies are not the issue, previously i have tried this

Comment: It is due to your present rule: `Use this set of 3 lines for each of your journals`

Comment: If you have that rule why do you need another to do same?

Comment: No matter what rules I used (have tried at least a dozen), I always got the redirect looping problem. When I try your rules, I only use the lines given by you in .htaccess.

Comment: ok can you post your complete & latest .htaccess file again in your question.

Comment: I used the exact code suggested by you as found at the bottom of my question.

Comment: If you see my comment above I asked you to replace your existing rules with my suggested rules. So move your existing file and create a new one with these 2 rules only and then retest.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get it. the .htaccess file only has your rules in it. All the lines are suggested by you.